# Rails order by a Hash value attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to sort the `domains` by `rank`, which is one of many keys of the `metrics` attribute.

This is an example of an object:

```
Domain.all.first.attributes
        => {
                    "id" => 1,
                  "name" => "example.com",
                "status" => "active",
               "country" => "Generic",
             "languages" => [],
                   "ips" => [],
            "created_at" => Sun, 25 Dec 2016 11:03:11 UTC +00:00,
            "updated_at" => Mon, 06 Feb 2017 18:17:01 UTC +00:00,
               "metrics" => {
                "internal_code" => 14803,
                            "language" => "",
                    "rank" => 98.4011625387248
               }
         }
```

Currently I simply order by `created_at`:

```
  def index
    @domains = filter(@domains.order(created_at: :asc))
```

How can I order the domains by `rank`?

Comment: Use @domains = filter(@domains.order(rank: asc))

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma rank is not an attribute. It's inside metrics.

Comment: and this is a model in db with child?

Comment: Domain is a model. metrics is an attribute of the model.

Comment: metrics = serialized as text?

Comment: @Fallenhero as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is it will sort the rank but as a string for ex. `0, 1, 11, 15 2, 21, 3, 40, 5`

You need to cast it to `float` or `integer` and then you can order it

```
Domain.order("(metrics ->> 'rank')::float")
#=> SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" ORDER BY (metrics ->> 'rank')::float
```

You can order it in **descending** if you want

```
Domain.order("(metrics ->> 'rank')::float DESC")
#=> SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" ORDER BY (metrics ->> 'rank')::float DESC
```

Comment: This only selects the rank field. I need to order the domains and return all information.

Comment: A combination of two answers did the trick: @domains = filter(@domains.order("(metrics ->> 'rank')::float DESC"))

Answer (score 1):

If it is a JSON field you can order in a following way.

```
@domains.order("metrics ->> 'rank' DESC")
```

Comment: Works but it's upside down, how to sort with highest rank first?

Comment: you'r previous answer worked but it ordered it by ascending order. How would you do the descending the values?. This doesn't work as rank is float.

Comment: @tom I thought the rank is string. I am happy that it worked for you.

Comment: now I see that it's not sorted well.. getting rank 98 90 10 9 and then 68 66 :/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
@domains = filter(@domains.order("metrics.rank"))
```

Comment: (pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "metrics"
LINE 1: SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" ORDER BY metrics.rank
                                                   ^
: SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" ORDER BY metrics.rank>